# Вызов C# функции из JavaScript кода

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net

Скажите, ребята, как можно вызывать C# функция из JavaScript-а, чтобы после выполнении получить результат из сервера в код бихайнде. Я использовал UDP протокол для отправки информации на сервис и получении ответа. Так как отправка и получение ответа выполняется в броузере, нужно использовать JavaScript.

Как реализовать скрипты и функции?

Comment: что откуда надо вызывать и где показывать результат?

Comment: из клиентской строрани отпровляется цифр например 2,на стороне сервиса виполняется сканирование какого то файла два раза а потом эти сканированные файлы должни отпровлятся в клиентскую часть

Comment: клиент это браузер?

Comment: да это браузер ;)

Comment: И это тоже вызов c# функции из js кода: `window.location.href = "Home/Index";`. Браузер создает запрос, на сервере по стандартному роутингу выполняется метод Index контроллера Home и возвращается результат.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам поможет AJAX.
Так как нет подробностей, то и ответ будет обобщенным - [тыц](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

пример:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnSendMessage').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var data = {
        'message': $('#TextBoxSender').val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'MessageHandler',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                alert("Сообщение доставлено");
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                alert("Внимание! Сообщение не доставлено!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Произошел сбой бла бла бла");
        }
    });
});
```

})

Метод обработки сообщения:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MeesageHandler(string data)
{
    var result = "Сообщение " + data + "принято"        
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Какие подробности нужно? ;0

Comment: в идеале описание задачи, просто даже из комментария можно строить догадки. Я так понял нужно вызвать функцию c# метод из js скрипта?В этом вам поможет ajax, например.

Comment: подробности добовил к тексту вопроса

Comment: 1. Для вызова функции из браузера можно использовать http post запрос. То есть используя стандартный элемент "input" и атрибут submit. Минус этого метода в том, что ответ сервера заставит страницу перезагрузиться.

Comment: 2. Я обычно использую AJAX и JQuery.

Comment: **Я обычно использую AJAX и JQuery**  как использовали в примере више?или всё так и есть пример ?

Comment: пологаю в моем случии ещё один такой скритп нужен для перехвата ответа который посылается из сервиса?и да если не сложно в скрипте добавте коментарии этимы техналогиями я не знаком

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48330/discussion-between---and-vardan-vardanyan).